# Simplify dict creation from non-defined type object

Tags: python, dictionary, simplification

I'm trying to keep a bit of code as efficient as possible and I think the aspect of it is just messy. If anyone want's to give a suggestion for a simplification of it I would really apreciate it.

```py
result = DotDict()
for name in dir(obj):
    value = getattr(obj, name)
    if not name.startswith('__') and not ismethod(value):
        result[name] = value
return result
```

In this case, the DotDict is a user class, derived from the dict class, being the only important thing the notion that it follows the same process that a dict does. The obj variable will any time, but will be mainly used as a class object from other classes.

I've seen a loop inside the dict creation but since I need both the `name` and `value` for the creation I couldn't make it work.

Comment: What about obj.\_\_dict\_\_ ? Otherwise, can you provide code that creates a dummy obj that shows a problem? Otherwise I don't see a problem here, and you can't really improve on going through all the things once. I might consider a dict comprehension with a helper function.

Comment: I ended up going for something like `{key: value for key, value in obj.__dict__.items() if not key.startswith('__') and not ismethod(value)}` and is working fine so far with all the test cases I put up with.